# i trema doesn't appear in RMarkdown LaTeX document

Tags: accents, r, markdown

I'm trying to write about naïve modeling, and have written the following header:

```
## Na\"{i}ve Modeling
```

That, however, and all variations like it, produce only something that looks like this:

> Na"{i}ve Modeling

What have I done wrong?

I'm using TeX Live 2017, version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18.

Comment: I thought I had done that with the line of code I had provided, had I not...?

Comment: @CampanIgnis RMarkdown is a way of combining Markdown with R code to produce PDF via conversion to LaTeX. So a traditional MWE is not applicable here. The fact that you can get a MWE LaTeX document to work is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can intersperse raw LaTeX and markdown in an `.Rmd` file, you can't put LaTeX into a markdown line itself, i.e., lines have to be either all markdown or all LaTeX.

A simple (and better) solution is to simply write the trema directly in the source:

```
## Naïve Modeling
```

Alternatively you could have written:

```
\section{Na\"ive Modeling}
```

or

```
\section{Naïve Modeling}
```

but obviously this defeats the purpose of using markdown.

[image: output of code]